# Recycler View Custom Scroll Movement

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj6hB.png)

I want a horizontal recycler view which moves radially like in that app.The view above recycler view shows the content of the middle element in the recycler view.Also when we scroll the recycler view, the right most element becomes bigger as it moves to the middle and the middle becomes smaller as it moves to the left.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HorizontalScrollView: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Comment: How can I ? Please elaborate if you can .

Comment: You basically add the HorizontalScrollView to your layout, and then add a LinearLayout as it's only child with orientation="horizontal", and then just add as many elements as you want and they will scroll horizontally. For the snapping feature, you will need a bit more work (check this: https://www.velir.com/blog/2010/11/17/android-creating-snapping-horizontal-scroll-view), and you will need to do some more work to have the right/left elements smaller than the center one.

Comment: Okay.But there's another problem the scrolling is radial; sort of like a semi cirlce , not an exact horizontal. How can I do that? Thanks :)

Comment: I would suggest making the HorizontalScrollView the entire height of the trajectory of the circles (so from the top of the center circle, to the bottom of the right/left circle). From there, you can set the position/size of each circle based on it's position. Hope this makes sense.